# ASP .net health monitoring event codes

Tags: asp.net, health-monitoring

Is there a list of all of the event codes and what they correspond to?

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation. I have found a list [here](http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/logging-in-mvc-part-5-the-model-and-data-layer/) but just wanted to verify that they didn't miss any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be what you're after:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.webeventcodes.aspx